# Store integer using character pointer

Tags: c++, c

I have  a character pointer and need to store 2 byte values in memory using this pointer.
Tried this

```
*dataConfigured =  configuredParameterCount;   
*++dataConfigured =  configuredParameterCount << 8;
```

Is there any better code other than this?

Comment: what's the type of `dataConfigured ` and `configuredParameterCount`

Comment: "Better code" could mean faster, consume less RAM memory, consume less program memory, safer, more readable, more maintainable... Also, we have no idea what types those variables are. Your question needs clarifications or none can answer it (they will try still, even though they can't, of course...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the type of `configuredParameterCount` is `short` (2 bytes), you can simply do this

```
*((short*)dataConfigured) = configuredParameter;
```

But do make sure that buffer pointed by `dataConfigured` has enough space.

As pointed out by @Calvin, this may cause problem on some computer architectures (although it will work on most common ones, like x86 and x64). But if you want to be on all architectures `memcpy` is safer bet (slower but safer).

Comment: Except, this isn't necessarily any faster. What if the OP is using an 8-bit CPU? You can't really optimize code without a specific system in mind.

Comment: This has the potential to break on architecture that alignment is critical (e.g. SPARC or custom MCU/SoC). Indeed gcc has such warning.

Comment: @Calvin I agree, now the more i think about it, OP code seems better option.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:

```
char dataConfigured[2];
uint16_t configuredParameterCount = 4711;
```

you can do:

```
memcpy(dataConfigured, &configuredParameterCount, sizeof(dataConfigured));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have

```
char* dataConfigured = ..;
short data = 123;
```

you can do

```
*((short*)dataConfigured) = data;
```

Be careful - you need to make sure that there is enough memory reserved.

Comment: Except, this isn't necessarily any faster. What if the OP is using an 8-bit CPU? You can't really optimize code without a specific system in mind.

Comment: @Lundin: As you stated in your comment to the question, it's not clear what better means. As premature optimization is not good, I wouldn't assume that "better" means "faster". In the first place, correct and readable code is usually "best" if it doesn't violate other constraints like performance. In this sense, I believe this answer is "better".